# Two different colored columns inside parent container

Tags: html, css

How can I style my .playing, .time-before, and .time-after and divs so that the .time-before and time-after divs split the .playing div into to equal width columns and fill the container height.

Live Link: https://riot-controls.herokuapp.com/

HTML:

```
<li each={ queue } onclick={ play }>
        <span>{ title }</span>
        <span>{ artist }</span>
        <span>{ stringifyTime(length) }</span>
        <div class='time-before'></div>
        <div class='time-after'></div>
      </li>
```

CSS:

```
.playing {
            color: orange;
        }
        .playing > .time-before {
            background-color: green;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 100%;
            float: left;
        }
        .playing > .time-after {
            background-color: red;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 100%;
            float: right;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`display:flex;` **basicly** will do this and can wrap into few lines or columns.

*height must be removed , background-color is sufficient*

```css
li {
  color: orange;
}
 .time-before {
  background-color: green;

}
 .time-after {
  background-color: red;
}
li {
  display:flex;
  }

li > div {flex:1;}
```

```html
<li each={ queue } onclick={ play }>
  <span>{ title }</span>
  <span>{ artist }</span>
  <span>{ stringifyTime(length) }</span>
  <div class='time-before'></div>
  <div class='time-after'></div>
</li>
```